# python regex find line1 and value after line 1, find line2 and value after line2...etc

Tags: python, regex

sorry the wording of the questions is a little confusing...

basically I have a document like the following... I need to use regex to get the name and year from each of these chunks into a dictionary

```
....
....
....
* name: (name1) *
* ...          *
* ...          *
* year: (year1) *
....
....
....
* name: (name2) *
* ...          *
* ...          *
* year: (year2) *
....
....
....
* name: (name3) *
* ...          *
* ...          *
* year: (year3) *
```

Need:

```
{'name1':'year1','name2':'year2','name3':'year3'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression.

```
>>> import re
>>> regex  = re.compile(r'(?s)name:\s*\((\w+)\).*?year:\s*\((\w+)\)')
>>> mydict = dict(re.findall(regex, data))
```

[**Working Demo**](https://eval.in/167533)

Answer (score 1):

Try something below regex that return the matched group and form the expected output manually.

```
/name:\s*\(([^)]*)\)|year:\s*\(([^)]*)\)/g
```

Here is [Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/pW5bL5) to check for the matched group.

This regex group every thing after `(` until `)` found.

Comment: Thanks, that work!, but could you provide an alternative with re.finditr()? actually, the real data doesn't have the ()... sorry